# How to load different files into different tables, based on file pattern?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I'm running a simple PySpark script, like this.

```
base_path = '/mnt/rawdata/'
file_names = ['2018/01/01/ABC1_20180101.gz',
               '2018/01/02/ABC2_20180102.gz',
               '2018/01/03/ABC3_20180103.gz',
               '2018/01/01/XYZ1_20180101.gz'
               '2018/01/02/XYZ1_20180102.gz']

for f in file_names:
  print(f)
```

So, just testing this, I can find the files and print the strings just fine.  Now, I'm trying to figure out how to load the contents of each file into a specific table in SQL Server.  The thing is, I want to do a wildcard search for files that match a pattern, and load specific files into specific tables.  So, I would like to do the following:

1. load all files with 'ABC' in the name, into my 'ABC_Table' and all files with 'XYZ' in the name, into my 'XYZ_Table' (all data starts on row 2, not row 1)
2. load the file name into a field named 'file_name' in each respective table (I'm totally fine with the entire string from 'file_names' or the part of the string after the last '/' character; doesn't matter)

I tried to use Azure Data Factory for this, and it can recursively loop through all files just fine, but it doesn't get the file names loaded, and I really need the file names in the table to distinguish which records are coming from which files & dates.  Is it possible to do this using Azure Databricks?  I feel like this is an achievable ETL process, but I don't know enough about ADB to make this work.

### Update based on Daniel's recommendation

```
dfCW = sc.sequenceFile('/mnt/rawdata/2018/01/01/ABC%.gz/').toDF()
dfCW.withColumn('input', input_file_name())
print(dfCW)
```

Gives me:

```
com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException:
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Oh, duh!!  It's a text file!!  This works:
dfABC = sc.textFile("rawdata/2018/01/01/ABC%.gz")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input_file_name` from `pyspark.sql.functions`
e.g.

```
withFiles = df.withColumn("file", input_file_name())
```

Afterwards you can create multiple dataframes by filtering on the new column

```
abc = withFiles.filter(col("file").like("%ABC%"))
xyz = withFiles.filter(col("file").like("%XYZ%"))
```

and then use regular writer for both of them.

Comment: Daniel, I updated my question based on your comment.  I'm getting another error.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check if your file system is properly mounted, /mnt/rawdata should be available using db fs utils